# How to account for solids of revolution around vertical lines to the right of the x axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to find the volume of a solid created by rotating the region enclosed between $x=y^2$ and $x=1$ around the line $x=8$.

Noting that the intersections of the functions occur at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, I can see that $y=\sqrt{x}$ is the upper function.

I tried using the formula $$\pi\int_0^1{((1+7)^2-(x^2+7)^2)dx}$$

However this doesn't yield the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the disc method, you have that $V=\int_{-1}^1 π(R^2-r^2)dy$ where $R=8-y^2$ and $r=8-1$,

so $\displaystyle V=\int_{-1}^1 \pi((8-y^2)^2-7^2)\;dy$.

Alternatively, using the shell method,

$\;\;\displaystyle V=\int_0^12\pi r(x)h(x)dx=\int_0^12\pi (8-x)(2\sqrt{x})\;dx$

Comment: Thanks! The main confusion I was having was the interval to use! I got it!

Comment: My radii were wrong as well, but I think that was because I kept messing with them thinking I was doing something wrong/

Comment: You're welcome -- I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating about a vertical line.  So you can use

- the "discs" or "washers" method, integrating with respect to $y$; or
- the "cylindrical shells" method, integrating with respect to $x$.

But you are trying to use the "discs" method and integrating with respect to $x$.

**Hint**: draw a picture!

Comment: Lets say I'll do the washer method. How would I proceed? I've tried several methods but they're all wrong.

Comment: I'm still really confused here.

Comment: Can you do it if you are rotating a region about a horizontal line?

Comment: Yes, with very little trouble.

Comment: If the the line to rotate about was x=-8, I could do the problem. But it is x=8 which is why I am confused I think

Comment: It is on the same side of the axis so I don't know how to account for it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which side of the axis the line is.  Can you do the rotation about $x=-8$, except whenever you have $-8$, write $x_0$ instead?  If so, then just changing $x_0$ to $8$ should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The area being rotated is $(1;8)\times(0;\sqrt x)$ or $(0;8)\times(0;1)\cup(1;y^2)\times(1;\sqrt 8)$

This is being rotated  around the vertical line $x=8$, so either use $2\pi \int_1^8 r~y\operatorname d x$ or $\pi(7^2+\int_1^{\sqrt 8} r^2\operatorname d y)$.

Can you figure out what $r$ is in terms of $x$ and $y$ respectively?